# pyrebase4 image file not downloading

Tags: python, firebase, download, firebase-storage, pyrebase

I'm trying to download the image file stored in Firebase, to use it as user profile picture later. Right now I can't get past the downloading part. I named the image as the user's UID, to download the proper image for every user. I used:

```
storage.child("/user_info/user_image/"+user_uid+".png").download("/user files/", user_uid+".png")
```

to download it. It seems to me that it does nothing. I checked the file name and path. It's correct. [Here's the file in the storage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txC3T.png)

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import pyrebase

firebaseConfig = {
    your config here
}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
auth = firebase.auth()
db=firebase.database()
storage=firebase.storage()

class MainApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')
    
    def login(self):
        email = self.root.get_screen("test1win").ids.user_mail.text
        password = self.root.get_screen("test1win").ids.password.text
        
        try:
            login = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
            self.root.current = "test2win"
            print("Login Success")
            global user_uid
            user_uid = login['localId']
            print(user_uid)
            global user_uinf
            user_uinf = []
            
        except:
            print("Invalid credentials.")
        
    def database_info(self):
        storage.child("/user_info/user_image/"+user_uid+".png").download("/user files/", user_uid+".png")
        userinf = db.child('userinfo').child(user_uid).get()
        for x in userinf.each():
            user_uinf.append(x.val())
        print(user_uinf)
        self.root.get_screen("test2win").ids.testwin2label.text = user_uinf[1]+" "+user_uinf[4]+", "+user_uinf[0]+", "+str(user_uinf[2])+", "+user_uinf[3]

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class TestWindow1(Screen):
    pass

class TestWindow2(Screen):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#: include testwindow1.kv
#: include testwindow2.kv

WindowManager:
    TestWindow1:
    TestWindow2:
```

testwindow1.kv

```
<TestWindow1>:
    name: "test1win"
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDTextField:
                id: user_mail
                hint_text: "E-Mail"
                size_hint_x: 0.8
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                font_size: 24
                mode: "rectangle"
            MDTextField:
                id: password
                hint_text: "Password"
                size_hint_x: 0.8
                font_size: 24
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                mode: "rectangle"
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "Login"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                on_release: app.login()
            Widget:
```

testwindow2.kv

```
<TestWindow2>:
    name: "test2win"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Screen:
            MDLabel:
                id: testwin2label
                text: "You're logged in"
            MDRaisedButton:
                id: button
                text: "Press to show database information"
                on_release: app.database_info()
            Widget:
```

- Python version 3.10.4
- Pyrebase4 version 4.5.0

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

storage.download("/user_info/user_image/"+str(user_uid)+".png", str(user_uid)+".png")